# Calling an ashx handler with jquery causes form action to post back to it

Tags: forms, jquery, httphandler, ashx

I'm calling an ashx handler with jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
    url: "handlers/getpage.ashx?page=" + pageName,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
               $('.hidden-slide-panel').append(response);
});
```

However when this hidden-slide-panel div gets populated, when I click on anything inside it, the form action value has been set now to getpage.ashx, rather than the calling pages form action. Is there a way to force it to use the calling pages action?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "data" property for ajax():

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
         url: "whatever.ashx",
         data: { page: pageName },
         success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Comment: How are you handling events in your hidden slide panel?

Comment: thanks, I'm using normal OnClick postbacks in my user control, the pageName variable is currently empty, the ashx  just returns an ascx Html Control rendered into html, but this is being wrapped in another <form> tag with its post action set to getpage.ashx, so I have a form within a form, which contains the control html! All I wanted is the control html.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do now. I would not recommend sending DOM elements across the wire like that, it causes a lot of problems (as I'm sure you are aware now). Since you are already using ASP .net web forms, I would advise using UpdatePanel and the Microsoft AJAX library. It's not the most efficient system, but it does work. Also, you could use a ContentPlaceholder and dynamically load your user control onto it. That way you don't have nested forms, which are not compatible with html standards.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to set the `form` back to its original value if it's changing:

```
document.forms[0].action = 'whatever';
// or
document.YourFormNameHere.action = 'whatever';
```